# Separar cadenas de texto en el último "." encontrado

Tags: javascript

¿Cómo podría separar el código **`100.V.H841.XG`** en el código sólo **`100.V.H841`** y la talla **`XG`**?

La talla siempre está al final y siempre va separada por un punto.

Esto es lo que intenté:

```
$(".o tr").each(function () {
    var id = $(this).find("td").eq(0).text();
    var codigo = $(this).find("td").eq(1).text();
    var codigoArray = codigo.split('.');
    var codigosolo = codigoArray[0];
    var tallasolo = codigoArray[1];
    console.log(codigosolo);
    console.log(tallasolo);
});
```

Comment: Por que no haces un separado=variable.split('.'); y luego part1=separado[0]+separado[1]+separado[2]; y en part2=separado[3]; no veo el sentido de hacerlo con espreciones regulares

Comment: pasa que tengo diferentes formato en una fila por eso queiro usar expreciones regulares 100.v-50.p o 100.1.60 no siempre va ser la misma forma del codigo

Comment: Dices que tienes distintos formatos y contenido variable. Preguntando positivo, que reglas tienes que te permite identificar la parte de la fila que quieres extraer? Siempre la parte después del ultimo punto? Siempre un código de talla entre puntos o termino de expresión?

Comment: con expreciones regulares quiero identificar que tipode formato tengo para proceder a una accion por eso necesito determinar que formato tiene el codigo para poder usar el codigo de arriba

Comment: Quizás no tienes nada que ver con cómo se almacenan los datos, pero creo que habría sido mejor mantener el código y la talla separados, y unirlos cuando fuera necesario.

Comment: el caso es que me lo pasan de esa forma yo no genero, me adapto

Comment: Cesar, los comentarios son para información transitoria. Los detalles relavantes que has compartido en comentarios, por favor agrégalos a la pregunta. En relación al código, que has incluido describe que hace. Mas detalles en [ask] y [mcve].

Comment: Pregunta: ¿lo que quieres separar está siempre al final y separado por un punto?

Comment: si seimpre esta al final y siempre por un punto

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Si lo que quieres separar siempre va a ir al final y separado por un punto ([como se indica en los comentarios](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/50554/separar-cadenas-de-texto-con-expresiones-regulares/50567#comment89205_50554)), quizás en lugar de usar expresiones regulares sería más sencillo utilizar algo como [`lastIndexOf`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/String/lastIndexOf) para separar los dos componentes.

`lastIndexOf` devuelve la posición de la última ocurrencia de la cadena/carácter especificado, entonces podrías dividir la cadena fácilmente a partir de ahí:

- Desde el inicio hasta el `lastIndexOf` será el código
- Desde el `lastIndexOf`+1 hasta el final será la talla

Algo como esto:

```js
function separaCodigoTalla(cadena) {
  var codigo = cadena.substring(0, cadena.lastIndexOf("."));
  var talla  = cadena.substring(cadena.lastIndexOf(".") + 1);
  
  return { codigo:codigo, talla:talla };
}

console.log(separaCodigoTalla("100.V.H841.XG"));
console.log(separaCodigoTalla("100.v-50.p"));
```

Answer (score 2):

Haciendo uso de expresiones regulares puedes usar esta como comentas que tienes diferentes formatos, asumiendo que el formato es algo como esto **"xxx.x.xx"**

usando la expresión regular `/^(.+)\.(.*)$/` y haciendo uso de [exec()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/exec) obtienes un arreglo con las posibles coincidencias

Lo que hace la ER es:

- **`(.+)`**: Coincide con cualquier carácter excepto un carácter de nueva línea para capturar la primera parte.
- **`\.`** : Decimos que se va a separar por un punto.
- **`(.*)`**: Coincide con cualquier carácter excepto un carácter de nueva línea para capturar la segunda parte.

El resultado nos dará un arreglo:

```
[
  "100.1.62",//texto evaluado
  "100.1",//primera coincidencia (\.*)
  "62"//segunda coincidencia (\.*)
]
```

**Ejemplo**

```js
function validate(){
  //teniendo en cuenta que en un input se carga x formato
  var cadena = document.getElementById("texto").value;
  
  var rgx = /^(.+)\.(.*)$/g;
  
  var arr = rgx.exec(cadena);//aplicando regex
  
  console.log(arr)//coincidencias
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="texto"/>
<button onclick="validate()">Go</button>
```